# How to match a SVO pattern with Textacy

Tags: python, nlp, textacy

How do you use Textacy's `pos_regex_match()` method to find subject-verb-object triples using their pseudo-regular-expression syntax? And yes, I'm aware of `textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples()`, but this function is very inaccurate and finds very little, so I'm attempting to build something more robust.

For the text:

```
text = "He recently wrote the sky is full of stars."
```

I'm trying:

```
svo_pattern = r'<DET>? <NOUN|PROPN|PRON>+ <VERB>?<ADV>*<VERB>+ <DET>? <NOUN|PROPN|PRON>+'
doc = textacy.Doc(text)
for sent in sents:
    matches = list(textacy.extract.pos_regex_matches(sent, svo_pattern))
    print(matches)
```

but it doesn't find anything. What's the flaw in my pattern? I've played with several variations of it, but nothing matches.

Comment: What SVO would you expect to extract from your example sentence?

Comment: @AnthonyHughes, `("He", "recently wrote", "the sky is full of stars")`

Comment: I've had a play with Textacy API but think the tool is not really cut out for what your trying to achieve. subject_verb_object_triples() is really for SVO languages and strictly SVO formed sentences. I also feel that pos_regex_matches is a bit too rigid for extracting an SVO from your sentence which is actually far more complex than a simple SVO sentence.
Would be very interested to see your work if you have any further examples to share.

Comment: Potentially an alternative here based on NLTK  https://github.com/klintan/py-nltk-svo